# Uninstall xcode in specific drive

Tags: xcode, uninstallation

I created a folder in /Developer called X-Code3.2.5

Here I have installed my Xcode and it's path is `Macintosh HD\Developer\X-Code3.2.5\Applications\Xcode`.

Now I want to uninstall it with

```
sudo with file path which takes command to uninstall  dev tool
```

Like this:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools
```

How to give correct path for the uninstall the Xcode from specified directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed it inside **/Developer/X-Code3.2.5** then you need to add **X-Code3.2.5** to the path.

> sudo /Developer/X-Code3.2.5/Library/uninstall-devtools